# Chrome: Hovering over div moves adjacent div: How to find culprit?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome, when I hover over a certain `div`, adjacent `divs` are moved to the left by 1px. When I click the `div` I was hovering over, the adjacent `divs` are moved back into their original position.

I'm wondering what's the best method of figuring out why this is happening? I've inspected the pertinent `divs` in inspector and can't see any reason why it's happening. Is there something inherent to Chrome that I'm missing?

[Issue can be seen here by hovering over the "Filter" box in the Office column.](https://www.dcturano.com/to-do_list/)

[Fiddle that's throwing a few errors.](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/89keypak/)

EDIT: Once I enable "Show paint rectangles" and hover over Filter, a div (shown in green) looks like it creates that little gap where the red arrow is:

[image: Arrow]

Comment: FWIW, I'm not seeing the issue in any browser. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome 38.0.2125.101. Make sure the cursor isn't on the filter div when the page loads, then hover over it. You'll see the div on the left move left by 1px.

Comment: So am I. Despite my best efforts, I just can't see it. My only advice is to ensure it's not a caching issue. Perhaps some improper styling stuck around from earlier in development, but that's a longshot.

Comment: I've tried clearing my cache multiple times and it still persists. *shrug*!

Comment: Just tried it on another computer, it's happening there as well.

Comment: fixed? nothing happens here on same Chrome version.

Comment: Still happening across multiple devices.

Comment: Edited to show Chrome's "Show paint rectangles" when the gap is created.

Comment: Can confirm seeing that issue here: Chrome v38, rMBP.

Comment: At least I'm not the only one! :)

Comment: I saw it momentarily, but now I can't reproduce it. In my opinion this appears to be some sort of chrome weirdness. I was not able to get it to happen until I started messing around with "Show paint rectangles".

Comment: My best suggestion is to first inspect a suspect element, then watch the DOM tree and the CSS classes and dimensions in the console while the change occurs. Normally in Chrome console the same element stays selected in the DOM tree even when you refresh the page. I look for changing styles and dimensions. Another thing that can be helpful is to set bright-colored backgrounds and borders on surrounding elements, so that you can more easily see which one is changing.

Comment: @JDSmith I used Inspect Element to try and pinpoint the div causing the adjustment, and I couldn't select that div. The divs I could select showed no change in their dimensions or position.

Comment: Could not reproduce either. Can you try restarting Chrome without extensions? Also, is your zoom level at 100% or other? Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle simplified so that we can play with it?

Comment: @Pipo I've added a fiddle to the OP, although it's throwing a few errors that I'm not sure how to get rid of. If someone can recommend how to fix the errors I'd edit the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. For your error maybe try to define some default content with `sDefaultContent`. Source: [this forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9030/using-fnrender-with-ajax-source-datatable#Item_1)

Comment: No one has commented in a while, but I want to echo what @trnelson suggested about checking the page with **no** extensions running. I've had plenty of weird moments where things shift or change when they shouldn't and the culprit was usually a Chrome extension injecting some CSS that interfered somehow.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your code? I used to be able to reproduce the issue but I am unable to now.

Comment: I was able to fix it, it was select2's CSS that was causing the issue. Had to do with one of the div's having overflow:visible. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: @Eric You should post that as an answer to your own question. You won't get the bounty, but it'll at least notify people that it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was select2's CSS that causing the issue. One of the div's overflow:visible was pushing other divs outwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is your tag:

```
mytag {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5695F3;
}
```

Use display:inline-block on hover will make not move other divs on hovering you element.

```
mytag:hover {
    color: #00287D;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display:inline-block;
    text-indent:0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.